# Problem with longitude and latitude in data (OpenCelliD)

Tags: excel, csv, coordinates, latitude-longitude

For an educational assignment, I am looking into the spread of telecommunication equipment in various European countries. However, I encounter a problem with the longitude and latitude in the data.

The data seems to include longitude and latitude data. However, if I am not mistaken, the data seems to be set to '0' or a very low or negative number. In this way, I am unable to map out the spread of the equipment.

The following columns are represented in the database:

- Radio
- MCC
- MNC
- LAC/TAC/NID
- CID
- Longitude
- Latitude
- Range
- Samples
- Changeable = 1
- Changeable = 0
- Created
- Updated
- Average signal

An example of one row of the CSV output can be found below.

GSM,213,3,1,1100,0,1.518565,42.503259,2285,14,1,1349890159,1471364600,0

Am I doing something wrong in processing the data?

I did try to open the data in different programs than Excel, but this does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: The MCC of 213 corresponds to Andorra, which has long/lat of about 1.5 and 42.5 degrees - so I think there is a erroneous "0" as the 6th entry which can be removed? This would shift the long/lat data into the correct place.

Comment: @gingerox I think this is the answer! :)

I will have to figure out where the zero stands for though, as the provided column headers do correspond with the total amount of columns. But I think this solves the problem :)

Thank you very very very much :)